# Should I use uppercase or camelcase in label enums?

Tags: java, enums, neo4j, cypher

The title says it all.

In [cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/), camelcase is used for labels. For instance `:Car` and `:Bike`. The API docs for [`Label`](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/Label.html) uses uppercase when defining each label in the enum, so then `Label.CAR.name()` will always be `CAR`, not `Car`.

Using camelcase fits in more nicely with cypher queries, but this conflicts with the Java standard for naming enum members. This forces me to use labels like `Label.BIKE_SEAT` instead of `Label.BikeSeat` in my graph database. Which one should I use?

Even though using uppercase for enum members is the correct way to do it in Java, I'm still a bit curious about why the Neo4j people then decided to represent labels as an enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First approach to a solution

To comply with the Java convention, I can override `Enum#toString()` and use that instead of `Enum#name()` which cannot be overridden. Then each member will have a constructor with its real Neo4j label as represented in the graph database:

```
public enum Label implements org.neo4j.graphdb.Label {
  CAR("Car"),
  BIKE("Bike"),
  BUS("Bus");

  private String name;

  private Label(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work well with methods such as `GraphDatabaseService#findNodesByLabelAndProperty(Label, String, String)` because it seems to be using `Label#name()` for matching instead of `Label#toString()` so it won't match nodes having camel case labels in the db.

### My working solution

Since overriding `Enum#toString()` doesn't work and since Neo4j uses `Label#name()` for everything internally, I'll need to override it anyway. So I ended up defining a class implementing `Label` which is able to override `Label#name()`:

```
public class Label implements org.neo4j.graphdb.Label {
  public static final Label CAR = new Label("Car");
  public static final Label BIKE = new Label("Bike");
  public static final Label BUS = new Label("Bus");

  private String name;

  private Label(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String name() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Externally, no changes are needed on the client side using the previous label enum.

Answer (score 7):

ORACLE DOC : `Because they are constants, the names of an enum type's fields are in uppercase letters.`

check : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html